# Variable not being set in jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to request data from a certain API and then i would need to put the response into variables but the variables are empty when i try to use them later on. When inserting the "data.id" f.e into a html code block it works like it should but variables are just left out.

Here is my code, I would be thankful for any help or advice.

```js
var id;
var title;
var posterPath;
var overview;
var releaseDate;
var actors = [];


var urlData = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + a.getAttribute('id') + '?api_key=a************************&language=en-US';

$.get(urlData, function(data) {
  console.log('data', data)

  id = data.id
  title = data.title
  posterPath = data.poster_path
  overview = data.overview
  realeaseDate = data.release_date

  document.getElementById("movieData").innerHTML += "<div data-role='header'><h2>" + data.title + "</h2><p>Release date: " + data.release_date + "</div><div data-role='content'><img src='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + data.poster_path + "' width=50% height=80%></div>"

  document.getElementById("description").innerHTML += "<p  style='white-space:normal;'>" + data.overview + "</p>"
})
```

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous, it's won't get the results right away!

Comment: You need to consume them in the callback

Comment: You need to use the  `.done(function(data) {.....);})` callback function

Comment: well he is using them in a callback isnt he?

Comment: This question should be reopened.

Comment: ``$.get(url, doneFunction)`` is the same as ``$.get(url).done(doneFunction);``. He's doing it correctly, and the marked duplicate does not answer his question - he does not ``return``, he assigns.